# Query for cores/core names or just query over all cores?

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I'm making a program to search on many solr servers, and each server can have many cores which names are unknown to me. Is there any way I can query the server for the name of the cores using solrnet, or even make a query over all cores?

The only other thing I can think of is to do a web request to solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS and parse the results but that seems unnecessarily complex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some [CoreAdmin](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Impl/SolrCoreAdmin.cs) support in SolrNet, however it currently only supports the STATUS command on a named core and not across the entire Solr instance. I believe parsing the web request to solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS will be your best option at this point.