# Get Solr status using SolrNet

Tags: solrcloud, solrnet

On a Solr instance I can get the status with this command: bin/solr status
Is there a way to get the status using SolrNet? Sometimes I need to import a lot of data and I would like halt the import if the heap size is >= 80%

Example query to get the status

```
http://my-solr.bigboss.com/solr/admin/collections?_=1573650195955&action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=json
http://my-solr.bigboss.com/solr/admin/info/system?_=1573650195955&nodes=10.0.1.138:8983_solr,10.0.1.232:8983_solr,10.0.5.244:8983_solr&wt=json
```

I am now using httpClient but are still interested if this can be done with SolrNet

```
 private List<string> GetSolrNodes()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            var url = _solrBaseUrl + "admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=json";
            var json = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
            var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            var liveNodes = (JArray)obj["cluster"]["live_nodes"];
            return liveNodes.HasValues ? liveNodes.Select(liveNode => liveNode.ToString()).ToList() : new List<string>();
        }
    }


private int GetSolrNodeWithMaxHeapSize()
    {
        var nodes = GetSolrNodes();

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            var stringNodes = nodes.Join(",");
            var url = _solrBaseUrl + $"admin/info/system?nodes={stringNodes}&wt=json";
            var json = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
            var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

            return nodes.Select(node => (int) obj[node]["jvm"]["memory"]["raw"]["used%"]).Concat(new[] {0}).Max();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at SolrNet [StatusCommand](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Commands/Cores/StatusCommand.cs), however it seems to work on a per core basis. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369993/2529954) also mention that.